# Security requirements for small tax software business

Tags: audit, compliance, standards

I have a client who does payroll and taxes and is looking for a web app to easily communicate and transfer tax related documents for clients. I would assume that the IRS or someone would have some standard on how this type of data should be handled. I haven't been able to find any good information on the subject and I don't know enough about the business domain of taxes yet to know how to ask for the information I am looking for. Any help, resources, suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRS has published [Publication 1075](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1075.pdf) which provides "Safeguards for Protecting Federal Tax Returns and Return Information"

> Internal Revenue Code Section 6103 stipulates that IRS must protect
> all the personal and financial information furnished to the agency
> against unauthorized use, inspection or disclosure. Other Federal,
> State and local authorities who receive federal tax information (FTI)
> directly from either the IRS or from secondary sources must also have
> adequate security controls in place to protect the data received.

Publication 1075 is very broad and deep.  Section 4 discusses Secure Storage, and Section 9 focuses on Computer Security Systems.

You should also look at FIPS 140-2 for additional encryption details.

**References**

[Encryption Requirements of Publication 1075](https://www.irs.gov/privacy-disclosure/encryption-requirements-of-publication-1075)

[NIST FIPS 140-2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.140-2.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!